# Fit MudCarousel resolution to image item content

Tags: css, blazor, mudblazor

I have the following template component for a dialog message to display a "full-screen" gallery of a few images (with varying resolutions).

```html
<MudDialog Style="max-width: 95vw; max-height: 90vh;">
    <DialogContent>
        <MudCarousel Style="THIS SHOULD BE DYNAMIC" Class="mud-width-full" ShowArrows="@(ShowControls && Images.Count > 1)" ShowBullets=false TData="object">
            @foreach (var image in Images)
            {
                <MudCarouselItem>
                    <MudImage Src="@("data:image/png;base64," + image)" Style="max-height: 80vh;" ObjectFit="ObjectFit.Contain" Elevation="5" Fluid />
                </MudCarouselItem>
            }
        </MudCarousel>
    </DialogContent>
</MudDialog>
```

`Images` is a Base64 `List<string>` parameter. The problem here is that I can't properly resize both the dialog and carousel containers to fit the images resolution without specifying fixed Width and Height properties in the Style parameter of the carousel component. Using 100% for either doesn't work as expected and the content size is ignored ending up with a 0x0 div.

I'm not sure if this is a CSS/MudBlazor issue or perhaps just wrong implementation on my part but I hope I explained the problem clearly enough.

Edit: Following the static logic and having access to an `Image` model containing resolution properties, this is what I'm trying now. It works but has some caveats, one being that images larger than 95vw or 90vh (max dialog size) will incorrectly expand the dialog in that axis and shrink down because of the object-fit attribute, so the problem is that the resizing values are set to the natural size and not the rendered size, some images might scaled down.

I mean, is this the best approach? This code makes me want to take a bath after touching it...

```
@inject ImageService ImageService

<div>
    <MudDialog Style="max-width: 95vw; max-height: 90vh;">
        <DialogContent>
            <MudCarousel Class="mud-width-full" Style=@($"width: {_width}px; height: {_height}px;") ShowArrows="@(Images.Count > 1)" ShowBullets=false TData="object" AutoCycle=false>
                @foreach (var image in Images)
                {
                    <MudCarouselItem Style=@($"width: {image.Width}px; height: {image.Height}px; max-width: 85vw; max-height: 80vh; margin: 1rem 0;") Transition="Transition.Fade">
                        <MudImage Src="@("data:image/png;base64," + LoadCardImage(image.Path))" Style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" ObjectFit="ObjectFit.Contain" Elevation="0" Fluid />
                    </MudCarouselItem>
                }
            </MudCarousel>
        </DialogContent>
    </MudDialog>
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MudDialogInstance MudDialog { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }

    private int _width;
    private int _height;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ResizeCarousel();
    }

    private void ResizeCarousel()
    {
        if (Images == null || Images.Count == 0) return;
        if(Images.Count == 1)
        {
            _width = Images[0].Width;
            _height = Images[0].Height;
        }
        else
        {
            _width = Images.Max(i => i.Width);
            _height = Images.Max(i => i.Height);
        }
    }

    private string LoadCardImage(string path) => ImageService.LoadImage(path);
}
```

Comment: did you ever find a sulution to this?